# Which is correct: "The next chapters will be dedicated to conduct case studies." or "The next chapters will be dedicated to conducting case studies."?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?

> "The next chapters will be dedicated to conduct case studies."

or

> "The next chapters will be dedicated to conducting case studies."

Please also indicate what the general rule is in this sort of cases (i.e., -ing or not -ing).

Comment: the latter is correct because "to" is a preposition here, as apposed to part of an infinitive

Comment: In the infinitive case, "to" is (technically) also a preposition, AFAIK. Albeit, with a very specific, dedicated purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following sentence:

> 50'000$ were **dedicated to conduct** case studies"

something is a pre-requisite for conducting the case studies.

It is equivalent to:

> 50'000$ were dedicated **in order** to conduct case studies"

---

However, in the sentence:

> "The next chapters will be **dedicated to conducting** case studies."

the chapters are not a pre-requisite, but only related **to** the **conducting** of the case studies.

If [headlinese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/headlinese) would not have been used, the sentence should have been written:

> "The next chapters will be dedicated to **the** conducting **of the** case studies."